# Moving local tasks to Mantis repository in Mylyn

Tags: task, mylyn, mantis

I have a mixture of local tasks and Mantis repository tasks. I'd like to move all my local tasks to the Mantis repository. Is there a way to do this easily? Currently the only way I can see is to recreate the task and specify it to be a task for the Mantis repository which will be cumbersome and time consuming.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I'm aware of is to *Clone* each local task and send it to the Mantis repository. You can right-click on the task editor header or on the task in the task list to access the context menu.

[image: Clone local task]

Afterwards, in the same menu, you can use the *Context - >Copy To...* to copy the task context to the new task, if needed.